# Why I can't call all Methods from another class?

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

I try to call a method from another class. I've added the reference and find the class. I'm able to call some methods of this class to but I can't call all of the methods in this class.

The main class is `public partial class` and the class with the methods I want to use is `private static class`. The method I try to call is `public static`. And there is no difference between the methods I can call and the method I can't call. That's the problem I don't understand. Please can someone explain?

```
namespace MyNamespace2
{
    private static class MyClass
    {
        public static void MyMethod() { }
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //can't call
            MyClass.MyMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, give some code

Comment: google "access specifiers in c#"

Comment: Private classes are internally available to their parent class. You would need to access the members of the private class through a public / internal  class or interface higher up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the class you're trying to access is private it doesn't matter if its methods are public, you can't access the class itself.

Consider it this way. If you're not allowed to enter New York, it doesn't matter if all of the houses are open inside the city, *since you can't get into the city itself*.

To get back to code however there is a case in which you can access private classes: if the calling function is part of a class that contains your private class.

If you have the freedom to manipulate the code for the class you're trying to access then you should attempt something similar to this:

```
class A {
  private static class B {
    public static void Foo() {}
  }

  public void Bar() {
    B.Foo();
  }
}
```

In this code you can call `B.Foo()` from any member function of `A`, but not from outside of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

You've written

> i want to use is private static class

Your private class and its methods, properties and fields is not available, even though they have a public modifier itself.
You have to read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/792326/Diving-into-OOP-Day-All-About-Csharp-Access-Modifi)

But if you are able to move your private class try this:

```
class Program
{
    private static class Test
    {
        public static void Foo() { }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test.Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i understand that. i changed the class from private to public but i still have the same problem. i cant call each method from this class. the main class is now public the class from which i call the method is public and the method is public but i cant call it.

Comment: ah ok. i had to rebuild the solution. now i can call the method. thanks alot for help :)

Comment: @Cendo Since you have resolved your problem, could you please accept an answer?

Comment: i am sorry sokkyoku,i dont understand why do you think i dont accept an answer?

Comment: Maybe you can't because the question is on hold but normally you can select one of the responses to your question as the accepted one, which marks it as the most adequate for futur viewers of the question

Comment: ok i would like to do that but i cant see any options to eccept an answer